# MySQL REGEXP - Select certain pattern of numbers and characters

Tags: mysql, regex

Anyone have a clue how I could go about trying to select a certain pattern of numbers with a `1` at the end?

Ex.

```
SELECT pattern FROM table WHERE pattern REGEXP '1_2+2_2+3_2+4_2&2016-06-09&1';
```

or

```
SELECT pattern FROM table WHERE pattern REGEXP '2_1&2016-06-09&1';
```

using the same number-underscore-number, ampersand, date, ampersand, number; just as long as that number 1 is at the end?

EDIT:

Actually, let me phrase it better. How do I use `REGEXP` to select an ampersand and the number 1 at the end of a string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex. Just use `LIKE`:

```
LIKE '%&1'
```

The `%` makes it not be anchored to the start of the string. `LIKE` is not regex, but closer to a glob syntax. It may be faster than regex, too.

Answer (score 1):

[The LIKE operator is used in a WHERE clause to search for a specified pattern in a column.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table 
WHERE column_name LIKE '%&1';
```

**Note:**
You can also use [LIKE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-comparison-functions.html) operator for searching from start not only from end.

[Here is an Example.](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_like)

```
SELECT column_name
FROM table 
WHERE column_name LIKE '&1%';
```